# ExtJS: What is the Grid Panel event to detect grid data changed

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I have a GridPanel and within the toolbar I have two buttons "Reject Changes" and "Save Changes". The code below shows what each button does, and so far things work as expected.

```
Ext.define('APP.view.MyGrid' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    ...

    initComponent: function() {    
        var me=this;
        me.store = myStore;         
        me.plugins = [
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 1, autoCancel: false
            }),
        ];          
        me.rejectBtn = {
            xtype:'button', id:'kbsGridCancelBtn', text:'Reject changes',
            handler: function() { me.store.rejectChanges(); }
        },      
        me.saveBtn = {
            xtype:'button', id:'kbsGridSaveBtn', text:'Save changes',
            handler: function() { me.store.sync(); }
        },      
        me.bbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
            items : [{ xtype: 'tbfill'},me.rejectBtn,'-',me.saveBtn] 
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

    ...

});
```

How to enable/disable the buttons (or any other action) **only if the grid data has been modified by the user**? I.e. only if any grid row/field becomes dirty (and vice-versa)? Which listener(s) should my code be listening to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in the question there's a [`CellEditing`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing) plugged-in to the Grid. By listening to the CellEditing Plugin's [`validateedit`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-validateedit) event, which is fired when data in the grid is changed, one can use the event's parameters to update the store's row using the Model instance's [`set`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-set) function. Of course after the required validation is done. The code decides whether to enable/disable the buttons based on what [`getModifiedrecords`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getModifiedRecords) returns.

Code:

```
...

listeners: {
    'validateedit': function(cep, e, eOpts) {
        var me = this,            
            rowIdx = e.rowIdx, // row index
            fieldName = e.field,
            newVal = e.value,
            storeRow = this.store.getAt(rowIdx);

        // assuming valid input, proceed with the below    
        storeRow.set(fieldName, newVal);

        // if modified records > 0 then enable buttons
        var enableButtons = Boolean(me.store.getModifiedRecords().length);

        if (enableButtons) {
            /* enable buttons */
        } else { /* disable buttons */ }        

    }, scope: this
}

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Ext.data.Store datachanged( this, eOpts ).
Fires whenever the records in the Store have changed in some way - this could include adding or removing records, or updating the data in existing records
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-datachanged

```
function dataChangedFun(store){
    // code here
}

myStore.on("datachanged", dataChangedFun, this);
```

And when you change the store's records manually then call `dataChangedFun(myStore);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I tried to listen to `datachanged`. But when I change data in the grid, and consequently change the store's record (of type `Ext.data.Model`) manually via `set()`, and then `commit()`, this event is still not fired :/

Comment: I didn't copy blindly your code sample as the code structure I've put above is simplified for communication's sake. Found another solution; will update this question with an answer after I've eaten something; thanks anyway, +1ed :)